# How the map function implemeted in racket

Tags: racket

How does the map function implemented in racket and why, recursion or iteration.

Maybe some implementation example

Comment: Just look at the source code... (map.rkt, in Dr.Racket right click, "open defining file")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## How to implement map

The `map` function walks a list (or multiple lists), and applies a given function to every value of a list. For example mappiing `add1` to a list results in:

```
> (map add1 '(1 2 3 4))
'(2 3 4 5)
```

As such, you can implement `map` as a recursive function:

```
(define (map func lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
    '()
    (cons (func (first lst)) (map func (rest lst)))))
```

Of course, `map` can accept any number of arguments, with each element passed to the given prop. For example, you can zip two lists together using `map list`:

```
> (map list '(1 2 3) '(a b c))
'((1 a) (2 b) (3 c))
```

To implement this variable arity map, we need to make use of the `apply` function:

```
(define (map proc lst . lst*)
  (if (empty? lst)
      '()
      (cons (apply proc (first lst) (map first lst*))
            (apply map proc (rest lst) (map rest lst*)))))
```

Now, this does assume all of the given lists have the same length, otherwise you will get some unexpected behavior. To do that right you would want to run `empty?` on all lists, not just the first one. But...when you use it, you get:

```
> (map list '(a b c) '(1 2 3))
'((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))
```

Note that `map` here calls itself recursively 3 times. A faster implementation might do some unrolling to run faster. A better implementation would also do proper error checking, which I have elided for this example.

## How Racket's map is implemented

If you open up DrRacket (using the latest Racket 7 nightly) and make the following file:

```
#lang racket

map
```

You can now right click on `map` and select `Open Defining File`. From here, you can see that `map` is renamed from the definition `map2`. The definition of which is:

```
(define map2
   (let ([map
          (case-lambda
           [(f l)
            (if (or-unsafe (and (procedure? f)
                                (procedure-arity-includes? f 1)
                                (list? l)))
                (let loop ([l l])
                  (cond
                   [(null? l) null]
                   [else
                    (let ([r (cdr l)]) ; so `l` is not necessarily retained during `f`
                      (cons (f (car l)) (loop r)))]))
                (gen-map f (list l)))]
           [(f l1 l2)
            (if (or-unsafe
                 (and (procedure? f)
                      (procedure-arity-includes? f 2)
                      (list? l1)
                      (list? l2)
                      (= (length l1) (length l2))))
                (let loop ([l1 l1] [l2 l2])
                  (cond
                   [(null? l1) null]
                   [else 
                    (let ([r1 (cdr l1)]
                          [r2 (cdr l2)])
                      (cons (f (car l1) (car l2)) 
                            (loop r1 r2)))]))
                (gen-map f (list l1 l2)))]
           [(f l . args) (gen-map f (cons l args))])])
     map))
```

Comment: Thanks for the details but my question was how map implemented in racket and not how to implement map by myself.

Comment: Fair point. I've updated the answer to also include the Racket7 map implementation.