# How to design a function that subtracts 2 from each number in a given list?

Tags: scheme, racket

Here is my code. My test result are always wrong and I don't know where the mistakes are and how to correct them.

```
(define (calculator op num lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst) empty]
        [else (cons (op num (first lst))
                    (calculator op num (rest lst)))]))

(define (sb lst)
  (calculator - 2 lst))
(define (calculator op num lst)
```

```
; test result:
(sb (list 2 3))
-->(list 0 -1)

(sb (list 5 6))
-->(list -3 -4)

(sb (list -1 -2))
-->(list 3 4)
```

Comment: I guess, maybe I should put lst infront of 2 and change my abstract function for calculator. otherweise it is 2 minus list item, instead of item -2

Comment: `(define (sb lst) (map (lambda (n) (- n 2)) lst))`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How the map function implemeted in racket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49820029/how-the-map-function-implemeted-in-racket)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by `(op num (first lst))`. When you run your code, it is essentially equivalent to `(- 2 (first lst))`. You are not subtracting `2` from every item in the list. Instead you are subtracting every item in the list from `2`. You are doing 2 - x instead of x - 2. To get the desired results, the arguments given to `-` should be flipped.

You could solve the problem by defining a "flipped subtraction" function that takes its arguments in a different order. For example:

```
(define (flipped-sub b a)
  (- a b))

(define (sb lst)
  (calculator flipped-sub 2 lst))
```

Or just use an anonymous lambda:

```
(define (sb lst)
  (calculator (lambda (num x) (- x num)) 2 lst))
```

Comment: Why would you write an auxiliary function for this when you could just fix the problem by changing: `(op num (first lst))` --> `(op num (first lst))` in the definition of `calculator`?

Comment: @adabsurdum I assumed that the OP wants the `calculator` function to handle all sorts of calculations (not just subtraction). If the OP wants to define both `divide-list` (`(/ list-item num)`) and `divide-num` (`(/ num list-item)`) using `calculator`, then the change you suggested will be somewhat arbitrary.