# Reversing list vs non tail recursion when traversing lists

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, scheme, lisp, racket

I wonder how do you, experienced lispers / functional programmers usually make decision what to use. Compare:

```
(define (my-map1 f lst)
  (reverse
   (let loop ([lst lst] [acc '()])
     (if (empty? lst)
         acc
         (loop (cdr lst) (cons (f (car lst)) acc))))))
```

and

```
(define (my-map2 f lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      '()
      (cons (f (car lst)) (my-map2 f (cdr lst)))))
```

The problem can be described in the following way: whenever we have to traverse a list, should we collect results in accumulator, which preserves tail recursion, but requires list reversion in the end? Or should we use unoptimized recursion, but then we don't have to reverse anything?

It seems to me the first solution is always better. Indeed, there's additional complexity (O(n)) there. However, it uses much less memory, let alone calling a function isn't done instantly.

Yet I've seen different examples where the second approach was used. Either I'm missing something or these examples were only educational. Are there situations where unoptimized recursion is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Tail recursion with accumulator

- Traverses the list twice
- Constructs two lists
- Constant stack space
- Can crash with malloc errors

## Naive recursion

- Traverses list twice (once building up the stack, once tearing down the stack).
- Constructs one list
- Linear stack space
- Can crash with stack overflow (unlikely in racket), or malloc errors

---

> It seems to me the first solution is always better

Allocations are generally more time-expensive than extra stack frames, so I think the latter one will be faster (you'll have to benchmark it to know for sure though).

> Are there situations where unoptimized recursion is better?

Yes, if you are creating a lazily evaluated structure, in haskell, you need the cons-cell as the evaluation boundary, and you can't lazily evaluate a tail recursive call.

---

Benchmarking is the only way to know for sure, racket has deep stack frames, so you should be able to get away with both versions.

The stdlib version is [quite horrific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49820029/how-the-map-function-implemeted-in-racket), which shows that you can usually squeeze out some performance if you're willing to sacrifice readability.

Given two implementations of the same function, with the same O notation, I will choose the simpler version 95% of the time.

Comment: Which Scheme implementation which will fare best on what is highly dependent on the implementation. eg. having a medium sized list of below a million elements and just make a copy of this which requires either trmc, deep stack, reverse or deep nested continuations. Best of 10 showed that while trmc did best in most situations since it didn't grow in time and memory the second best was impossible to guess in advance.

Comment: It seems like the accumulator version is faster on my computer after all. Given a goddamn slow win32 machine and a simple add1 function, accumulator is 2-4 times faster (cpu time without gc) and 4-8 times faster in terms of gc only time (on 1-4 million lists of ints). What's confusing is that an ordinary map is 1.2-1.5 times faster than accumulator. However, it's - as you've pointed out - implemented using simple reucrsion. Maybe it's a matter of how the let form works with recursion?
Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

When possible, I use higher-order functions like `map` which build a list under the hood. In Common Lisp I also tend to use `loop` a lot, which has a `collect` keyword for building list in a forward way (I also use the `series` library which also implements it transparently).

I sometimes use recursive functions that are not tail-recursive because they better express what I want and because the size of the list is going to be relatively small; in particular, when writing a macro, the code being manipulated is not usually very large.

For more complex problems I don't collect into lists, I generally accept a callback function that is being called for each solution. This ensures that the work is more clearly separated between how the data is produced and how it is used.

This approach is to me the most flexible of all, because no assumption is made about how the data should be processed or collected. But it also means that the callback function is likely to perform side-effects or non-local returns (see example below). I don't think it is particularly a problem as long the the scope of the side-effects is small (local to a function).

For example, if I want to have a function that generates all natural numbers between 0 and `N-1`, I write:

```
(defun range (n f)
  (dotimes (i n)
    (funcall f i)))
```

The implementation here iterates over all values from 0 below N and calls F with the value I.

If I wanted to collect them in a list, I'd write:

```
(defun range-list (N)
  (let ((list nil))
    (range N (lambda (v) (push v list)))
    (nreverse list)))
```

But, I can also avoid the whole `push/nreverse` idiom by using a queue. A queue in Lisp can be implemented as a pair `(first . last)` that keeps track of the first and last cons cells of the underlying linked-list collection. This allows to append elements in constant time to the end, because there is no need to iterate over the list (see *Implementing queues in Lisp* by P. Norvig, 1991).

```
(defun queue ()
  (let ((list (list nil)))
    (cons list list)))

(defun qpush (queue element)
  (setf (cdr queue)
        (setf (cddr queue)
              (list element))))

(defun qlist (queue)
  (cdar queue))
```

And so, the alternative version of the function would be:

```
(defun range-list (n)
  (let ((q (queue)))
    (range N (lambda (v) (qpush q v)))
    (qlist q)))
```

The generator/callback approach is also useful when you don't want to build all the elements; it is a bit like the lazy model of evaluation (e.g. Haskell) where you only use the items you need.

Imagine you want to use `range` to find the first empty slot in a `vector`, you could do this:

```
(defun empty-index (vector)
  (block nil
    (range (length vector)
           (lambda (d) 
             (when (null (aref vector d))
               (return d))))))
```

Here, the `block` of lexical name `nil` allows the anonymous function to call `return` to exit the block with a return value.

In other languages, the same behaviour is often reversed inside-out: we use iterator objects with a cursor and next operations. I tend to think it is simpler to write the iteration plainly and call a callback function, but this would be another interesting approach too.

Comment: always enlightening to read your posts. i love this simple `queue` implementation.

Comment: @Thankyou thanks! The queue functions were written from memory, based on"Implementing queues in Lisp" from Norvig I guess

Comment: correct, _PAIP_ is also one of the best way to start programming.

Comment: After taking some hard time thinking I finally managed to understand how this queue works) It would be harder to implement in racket though, since it heavily discourages usage of mutable structures. And well, one might argue we should adhere to the functional style. On the other hand, I think it's ok to do whatever we want as long as we know what we're doing) Anyway, thanks for your reply!

Comment: @heinwol see Racket manual for [_Mutable Pairs and Lists_](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/mpairs.html). Immutable structures are favourable in most circumstances but `mcons` definitely has viable use cases.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to make recursion preserving iterative process.

I usually do continuation passing style directly.  This is my "natural" way to do it.

One takes into account the type of the function.  Sometimes you need to connect your function with the functions around it and depending on their type you can choose another way to do recursion.

You should start by solving "the little schemer" to gain a strong foundation about it.  In the "little typer" you can discover another type of doing recursion, founded on other computational philosophy, used in languages like agda, coq.

In scheme you can write code that is actually haskell sometimes (you can write monadic code that would be generated by a haskell compiler as intermediate language).  In that case the way to do recursion is also different that "usual" way, etc.

Comment: nice to see another cps recommendation here. and hats off to _the little schemer_ :D

Answer (score 2):

**false dichotomy**

You have other options available to you. Here we can preserve tail-recursion and `map` over the list with a single traversal. The technique used here is called *continuation-passing style* -

```scm
(define (map f lst (return identity))
  (if (null? lst)
      (return null)
      (map f
           (cdr lst)
           (lambda (r) (return (cons (f (car lst)) r))))))

(define (square x)
  (* x x))

(map square '(1 2 3 4))
```

```scm
'(1 4 9 16)
```

This question is tagged with `racket`, which has built-in support for [delimited continuations](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/cont.html). We can accomplish `map` using a single traversal, but this time without using recursion. Enjoy -

```scm
(require racket/control)

(define (yield x)
  (shift return (cons x (return (void)))))

(define (map f lst)
  (reset (begin
           (for ((x lst))
             (yield (f x)))
           null)))

(define (square x)
  (* x x))

(map square '(1 2 3 4))
```

```scm
'(1 4 9 16)
```

It's my intention that this post will show you the detriment of pigeonholing your mind into a particular construct. The beauty of Scheme/Racket, I have come to learn, is that *any* implementation you can dream of is available to you.

I would highly recommend [*Beautiful Racket*](https://beautifulracket.com) by Matthew Butterick. This easy-to-approach and freely-available ebook shatters the glass ceiling in your mind and shows you how to think about your solutions in a language-oriented way.

Comment: Wow, now I see how this "continuation-passing style" can be used! And I thought it was only useful for threading or sth like that. It also seems to be faster than naive recursion! But it's still slower than accumulator. It also might be that it uses several times (~3?) more memory than accumulator: each capture have to store additional references to f and lst. Or maybe it gets optimized somehow, I don't know how it works)

Comment: Nonetheless, your method is really beautiful! And your answer is truly inspiring! Thank you Thank you!

Comment: @heinwol linear recursion with accumulator and reverse is probably the most efficient and fastest way to do `map` specifically. But continuation-passing style and delimited continuations make it possible to do things that aren't possible with linear recursion alone. This is a nice way to learn about them because you now have seen `map` implemented in multiple ways. Next time you encounter continuation-passing style or delimited continuations, they won't feel so foreign :D